# RStudio Programmatically Set Directory in Files Tab

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to programmatically set directory in the Files tab within RStudio. The version of RStuido is 1.1.453. I have tried looking within `rstudioapi` package but the relevant functions that I found `selectDirectory()` and `selectFile()` open an interactive file tree browser and they do not change the Files tab content. I know that one can use `setwd()` then in the Files tab use More -> Go To Working Directory but I need to do this fully programmatically.
In summary I wish there was a function `setFilesTab(dirpath = )` which I could submit and the Files tab would change the focus to the `dirpath`.

Thank you so much for your help and time!

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi/issues

Comment: it looks like `selectFile` has a `path` argument? https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi/blob/e87b481fee0f156015f8c834d8faf2c9f36a6aa6/R/stubs.R#L175-L182

Comment: Thank you @MichaelChirico, the both `selectFile()` and `selectDirectory` have `path` argument and it is used as a starting point for the interactive file browser. Unfortunately this has no efffect on Files tab within RStudio. I guess you are alluding to open a feature suggestion in GitHbub repo for `rstudioapi` package.

Comment: `rstudioapi::filesPaneNavigate()` should do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my first post on this website; so, hello to all.

I am excited to be part of this community.

Just adding to the answer by RoyalTS, I wanted to specifically tell the files tab to open the working directory.  This code works:

```
rstudioapi::filesPaneNavigate(getwd())
```

Cheers,

Jason